# Canvg conversion - weird behavior when using a fill url

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, canvg

I'm trying to convert svg to canvas using the canvg js lib.

The original svg contains a rect which has a fill attribute of url to a svg pattern. When I convert the svg to canvas using canvg:

`canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), svg);`

The image of the rect fill changes its proportions (The width and the height change).

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/229/) shows the svg before and after the conversion.

Does anyone have an idea for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/230/

I'm changed

```
<pattern id="img1" width="20" height="20">
```

to

```
<pattern id="img1" width="200" height="200">
```

And it's work.

Comment: Thanks, but in my app http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/231/ I have many circles, and changing the pattern size doesn't help, since they are different from each other.

Comment: I want the canvas to look exactly as the svg. can you try to edit the second fiddle?